# Highcharts not displaying chart correctly/not reading array properly

Tags: java, arraylist, highcharts

I am reading in some information from a database and putting it in to an arraylist for highcharts to be able to read. The Arraylist is in the form of [String,int] and it represents a date/number of users. It looks like this

```
[[2014-06-25, 35], [2014-06-26, 48], [2014-06-27, 60], [2014-06-28, 14], [2014-06-29, 8], [2014-06-30, 26], [2014-07-01, 21], [2014-07-02, 32], [2014-07-03, 33], [2014-07-04, 17], [2014-07-05, 18], [2014-07-06, 14], [2014-07-07, 26], [2014-07-08, 18], [2014-07-09, 26], [2014-07-10, 21], [2014-07-11, 1]]
```

I got to feed that in to my highchart, which looks like this:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Users',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'subtitle',
        x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of users'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Users',
        data: '<%=combined%>'
    }]
});
```

But it comes out like this 
[image: result]

I'm trying to do this in a jsp file, can highcharts read java ArrayLists?

Thanks

Comment: In JS string are in the form ["2014-06-26", 48], and you can use tickInterval to set more distance between ticks. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
```

to

```
xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
```

One more thing - date format should be like this -  `[Date.UTC(2014,06,25), 35]` - Run it as it is to get idea..

http://jsfiddle.net/8jwHV/4/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Users',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'subtitle',
    x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of users'
    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
    }]
},
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '°C'
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    borderWidth: 0
},
series: [{
    name: 'Users',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014,06,25), 35], 
                [Date.UTC(2014,06,26), 40], 
                [Date.UTC(2014,06,27), 41], 
                [Date.UTC(2014,06,28), 80], 

            ]
        }, ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes the x axis now go up 0 - 50 - 100 - 150 etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry change it to - datetime instead of date and use above date format, you need to convert your data in that format- check jsfiddle also..

Comment: Thanks Ninad, I am parsing my String date like so

Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(rs.getString(1));

and that returns the date like "Wed Jun 25 00:00:00 BST 2014" but highcharts still doesn't seem to read it. Should the date in the array that highcharts reads be exactly yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println("Date.UTC("+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd").format(date)+")");` This will give you required format... `Date.UTC(2012,02,02)`

Comment: Using this output create your array and pass it to graph like - `[[Date.UTC(2012,02,02),56],[Date.UTC(2012,02,02),60]` etc..

Comment: I think my problem is that I am creating a java arraylist and then highcharts is trying to read it as a javascript arraylist. Would that be a problem? I took your advice and the arraylist is definitely in the correct form because when I substitute the output from printlning it out instead of"'<%=combined%>'" in to the data field in my highcharts code it works.

Comment: then you can print `<%=combined%>` on the jsp outside the graph, to check what is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
       tickInterval: 50
}
```

Comment: Date is not supported, only datetime.